# HTML form not submitting to PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

I have an html form set to submit to itself with `$SERVER['PHP_SELF']` but the form does not seem to be able submit, instead it simply returns the same form when I click submit (with and input of type `submit`.

NOTE: the actual code is too long to post here, and I've included all that I think is necessary. The form in question is actually a duplicate of another (which works perfectly) but this one doesn't.

EDIT: I was advised to eventually post the code

SECOND EDIT: I actually removed the tag `enctype='multipart/formdata'` on the `form` tag, and the code script now works. But, I need that `enctype` to be able upload the images. Does anyone know how I can work around that?

```
<?php
include 'templates/inc/header.php';
include 'templates/inc/system_helpers.php';
include 'config/config.php';
?>

<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

ob_start();
$listing_saved = FALSE;

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    // property type
    $property_type = isset($_POST['property_type']) ? $_POST['property_type'] : '';

    // property details
    $area_sq = isset($_POST['area_sq']) ? $_POST['area_sq'] : '';
    $location = isset($_POST['ex_location']) ? $_POST['ex_location'] : '';
    $bedrooms = isset($_POST['bedrooms']) ? $_POST['bedrooms'] : '';
    $bathrooms = isset($_POST['bathrooms']) ? $_POST['bathrooms'] : '';
    $furnished = isset($_POST['furnished']) ? $_POST['furnished'] : '';

    // additional information
    $description = isset($_POST['description']) ? $_POST['description'] : '';
    $garden = isset($_POST['garden']) ? $_POST['garden'] : '';
    $pool = isset($_POST['pool']) ? $_POST['pool'] : '';
    $flatlet = isset($_POST['flatlet']) ? $_POST['flatlet'] : '';
    $garage = isset($_POST['garage']) ? $_POST['garage'] : '';
    $parking = isset($_POST['parking']) ? $_POST['parking'] : '';
    $parking_spaces = isset($_POST['parking_sapces']) ? $_POST['parking_spaces'] : '';

    // pricing
    $price = isset($_POST['price']) ? $_POST['price'] : '';

    // contact person
    $first_name = isset($_POST['f_name']) ? $_POST['f_name'] : '';
    $last_name = isset($_POST['l_name']) ? $_POST['l_name'] : '';
    $email_address = isset($_POST['email_address']) ? $_POST['email_address'] : '';
    $phone = isset($_POST['phone']) ? $_POST['phone'] : '';
    $physical_address = isset($_POST['physical_address']) ? $_POST['physical_address'] : '';
    $region = isset($_POST['region']) ? $_POST['region'] : '';

    // legal consent
    $consent = isset($_POST['consent']) ? $_POST['consent'] : '';
    $isFNBBanked = isset($_POST['isFNBBanked']) ? $_POST['isFNBBanked'] : '';
    $account_holder = isset($_POST['account_holder']) ? $_POST['account_holder'] : '';
    $account_number = isset($_POST['account_number']) ? $_POST['account_number'] : '';
    $commercialAcceptance = isset($_POST['commercialAcceptance']) ? $_POST['commercialAcceptance'] : '';
    $isInfoCorrect = isset($_POST['isInfoCorrect']) ? $_POST['isInfoCorrect'] : '';
    $optionToOptOut = isset($_POST['optionToOptOut']) ? $_POST['optionToOptOut'] : '';
    $isAuthorized = isset($_POST['isAuthorized']) ? $_POST['isAuthorized'] : '';

    // create an uploads directory
    if (!is_dir(UPLOAD_DIR)) {
        mkdir(UPLOAD_DIR, 0777, true);
    }

    /*
     * List of file names to be filled in by the upload script 
     * below and to be saved in the db table "images" afterwards.
     */
    $file_names_to_save = [];

    $allowed_mime_types = explode(',', UPLOAD_ALLOWED_MIME_TYPES);

    // capture the image uploads
    if (!empty($_FILES)) {
        if (isset($_FILES['images']['error'])) {
            foreach ($_FILES['images']['error'] as $uploadedFileKey => $uploadedFileError) {
                if ($uploadedFileError === UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE) {
                    $errors[] = 'You did not provide any files.';
                } elseif ($uploadedFileError === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                    $uploadedFileName = basename($_FILES['images']['name'][$uploadedFileKey]);

                    if ($_FILES['images']['size'][$uploadedFileKey] <= UPLOAD_MAX_FILE_SIZE) {
                        $uploadedFileType = $_FILES['images']['type'][$uploadedFileKey];
                        $uploadedFileTempName = $_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$uploadedFileKey];

                        $uploadedFilePath = rtrim(UPLOAD_DIR, '/') . '/' . $uploadedFileName;

                        if (in_array($uploadedFileType, $allowed_mime_types)) {
                            if (!move_uploaded_file($uploadedFileTempName, $uploadedFilePath)) {
                                $errors[] = 'The file "' . $uploadedFileName . '" could not be uploaded.';
                            } else {
                                $file_names_to_save[] = $uploadedFilePath;
                            }
                        } else {
                            $errors[] = 'The extension of the file "' . $uploadedFileName . '" is not valid. Allowed extensions: JPG, JPEG, PNG, or GIF.';
                        }
                    } else {
                        $errors[] = 'The size of the file "' . $uploadedFileName . '" must be of max. ' . (UPLOAD_MAX_FILE_SIZE / 1024) . ' KB';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (!isset($errors)) {

        // add captured data into database
        $query = 'INSERT INTO property (
                            propertytype_id,
                            land_area,
                            ex_location, 
                            bedrooms, 
                            bathrooms,
                            is_furnished, 
                            short_desc, 
                            has_garden, 
                            has_pool, 
                            has_flatlet, 
                            has_parking,
                            parking_spaces,
                            price) 
                            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';

        //prepare the statement
        $stmt = $connection->prepare($query);

        //bind the parameters
        $stmt->bind_param('iisiissssssii', $property_type, $area_sq, $location, $bedrooms, $bathrooms, $furnished, $description, $garden, $pool, $flatlet, $parking, $parking_spaces);

        //execute the statement
        $stmt->execute();

        //grab the last car insert ID
        $last_insert_id = $connection->insert_id;

        // insert into persons table
        $persons_sql = 'INSERT INTO person (
                                    property_id, 
                                    firstname, 
                                    lastname, 
                                    email_address, 
                                    phone, 
                                    city,
                                    region) 
                                    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';

        $stmt = $connection->prepare($persons_sql);
        $stmt->bind_param('isssiss', $last_insert_id, $first_name, $last_name, $email_address, $phone, $physical_address, $region);
        $stmt->execute();

        // grab the last person's id
        $last_person_insert = $connection->insert_id;

        // insert into legal table
        $legal_sql = 'INSERT INTO legal (
                                    person_id, 
                                    consent, 
                                    isFNBBanked,
                                    account_holder, 
                                    account_number,
                                    commercialAcceptance,
                                    isInfoCorrect,
                                    optionToOptOut,
                                    isAuthorized 
                                    ) 
                                    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';

        $stmt = $connection->prepare($legal_sql);
        $stmt->bind_param('isssissss', $last_person_insert, $consent, $isFNBBanked, $account_holder, $account_number, $commercialAcceptance, $isInfoCorrect, $optionToOptOut, $isAuthorized);
        $stmt->execute();

        // close the statement
        $stmt->close();

        // save a record for each uploaded file
        foreach ($file_names_to_save as $file_name) {

            $query = 'INSERT INTO images (
                        property_id, 
                        image_name) 
                        VALUES (?, ?)';

            $stmt = $connection->prepare($query);
            $stmt->bind_param('is', $last_insert_id, $file_name);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();
        }

        $listing_saved = TRUE;
    }
}
?>

<!-- Page Contents -->
<div class="form-container">

    <div class="sticky-anchor"></div>
    <div class="banner">
        <img src="./assets/MarketSquare banner for PROPERTY.jpg" alt="Market Square Form Banner">
    </div>

    <?php display_message(); ?>

    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <!-- PROPERTY DETAILS -->
        <div class="section-one">

            <h3>Property Details</h3>

            <div class="text-fields">
                <div class="extra-fields">
                    <select name="property_type" id="property-type" class="select">

                        <option value="0">Property Type</option>
                        <?php
                        $query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM property_type");

                        if (mysqli_num_rows($query)) {
                            $i = 0;
                            while ($propertytype = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                        ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $propertytype['propertytype_id']; ?>"><?php echo $propertytype['type_name']; ?></option>
                        <?php
                                $i++;
                            }
                        }
                        ?>

                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="text-fields">
                <div class="extra-fields">
                    <input type="text" name="area_sq" placeholder="Area (in square metres)" required>
                    <input type="text" name="location" placeholder="Location (e.g. Veki's Village, Mountain Drive, Mbabane)">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="text-fields selected">
                <div class="extra-fields">
                    <input type="text" name="bedrooms" placeholder="No. of Bedrooms" required>
                    <input type="text" name="bathrooms" placeholder="No. of Bathrooms">
                </div>
            </div>

            <label class="check-box">Furnished
                <input type="checkbox" name="furnished" value="Yes">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>

        </div>

        <!-- ADDITIONAL INFORMATION -->
        <div class="section-two">

            <h3>
                Additional Information
                <span> (Provide details about additional features)</span>
            </h3>
            <div class="extra-fields">
                <textarea name="description" id="description" cols="30" rows="4" placeholder="Separate your items with a comma ( , )"></textarea>
            </div>

            External Features <span>(tick where appropriate)</span>
            <div class="checks">
                <label class="check-box">Garden
                    <input type="checkbox" name="garden" value="Available">
                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>

                <label class="check-box">Swimming Pool
                    <input type="checkbox" name="pool" value="Available">
                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>

                <label class="check-box">Bedsitter/flatlet
                    <input type="checkbox" name="flatlet" value="Available">
                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
                <label class="check-box">Garage
                    <input type="checkbox" name="garage" value="Available">
                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>

                <label class="check-box">Open Parking
                    <input type="checkbox" name="parking" value="Available" id="parking-space" onclick="show_input()">
                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
                <input type="text" name="parking_spaces" id="parking" placeholder="Number of parking spaces">

            </div>

            <div class="file-input">
                Photos: <span>(max. 12, in all angles incl. interior)</span>
                <input type="file" name="images[]" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png, .gif, .webp" id="imgUpload" multiple required>
            </div>

        </div>

        <!-- PRICING -->
        <div class="section-two pricing">

            <h3>
                Give it a Price
                <span>(The sale price you wish to attach, based on the Valuation Report)</span>
            </h3>
            <div class="extra-fields">
                <input type="text" name="price" placeholder="E " required>
            </div>

        </div>

        <!-- CONTACT PERSON -->
        <div class="section-three">

            <h3>Contact Person</h3>
            <div class="text-fields">
                <div class="extra-fields">
                    <input type="text" name="f_name" placeholder="First name" required>
                    <input type="text" name="l_name" placeholder="Last name">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="text-fields">
                <div class="extra-fields">
                    <input type="email" name="email_address" placeholder="Email address">
                    <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone number" required>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="text-fields">
                <div class="extra-fields">
                    <input type="text" name="physical_address" placeholder="Town/city (e.g. Lobamba)">
                    <input type="text" name="region" placeholder="Region (e.g. Hhohho)" required>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <!-- LEGAL -->
        <div class="section-four">

            <h3>Legal</h3>
            <div class="consent">
                <input type="checkbox" name="consent" value="Given" required>
                I/We give 
            </div>

            <div class="consent">
                <input type="checkbox" name="consent_1" value="Yes" required>
                I/We confirm .
                <div class="extra-fields">
                    <input type="text" name="acount_name" placeholder="Account Name">
                    <input type="text" name="account_number" placeholder="Account Number" required>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="consent">
                <input type="checkbox" name="consent_3" value="Accepted" required>
                I/We agree .
            </div>

            <div class="consent">
                <input type="checkbox" name="consent_4" value="Confirmed" required>
                I/We confirm 
            </div>

            <div class="consent">
                <input type="checkbox" name="consent_5" value="Acknowledged" required>
                I/We acknowledge 
            </div>

            <div class="consent">
                <input type="checkbox" name="consent_6" value="Confirmed" required>
                 authorised.
            </div>

        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
    </form>

    <?php
    if ($listing_saved) {

        redirect('listings_Properties.php', 'Your submition has been received. Please give us time to verify validity of the provided information.', 'sucess');
    }
    ?>

</div>
<?php include 'templates/inc/footer.php' ?>
```

code for the redirect script is

```
<?php

function redirect($page = FALSE, $message = NULL, $message_type = NULL){
    if(is_string($page)){
        $location = $page;
    }
    else{
        $location = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
    }

    // check for message
    if($message != null){
        $_SESSION['message'] = $message;
    }
    
    // check for message type
    if($message_type != null){
        $_SESSION['message_type'] = $message_type;
    }

    //...then redirect
    header('Location: '. $location);
    exit;
}

// display the message
function display_message(){

    if(!empty($_SESSION['message'])){
        $message = $_SESSION['message'];

        if(!empty($_SESSION['message_type'])){
            $message_type = $_SESSION['message_type'];

            if($message_type == 'error'){
                echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" id="msg">'.$message.'</div>';
            }
            else{
                echo '<div class="alert alert-success" id="msg">'.$message.'</div>';
            }
        }

        unset($_SESSION['message']);
        unset($_SESSION['message_type']);
    }
    else{
        echo '';
    }
}
```

Comment: Even so, you are going to have to post enough of your code that it reproduces the problem.

Comment: Alright @LeeTaylor, let me do so

Comment: How do you know it's not submitting?  Try echoing something after `if (isset($_POST['submit']))`

Comment: Echoed out some of the values and they are echoed on to the screen. Thanks @Barmar, at least now I can a way foward

Comment: Seems like something is going wrong with `ob_start()`. Check your log for `Headers already set` warnings and fix the cause.

Comment: what is the code in the redirect PHP function ?

Comment: @KenLee, please the new edit for your reference

Comment: @Barmar, nothing on the error logs. I've tried removing and re-adding ```ob_start()``` but nothing happens

Comment: @KenLee, please note that there is another duplicate script which perform more or less the same operation, I just simply changed the variables and database tables, and it works just fine with that redirect script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to everyone who contributed towards me figuring out what really the problem.

What I didn't realize was that the `max file upload` in the script is set to 2MB while I was uploading images larger than 2MB, and my error handler wasn't working to actually prompt that. Again thank you to everyone who had suggestions. They really helped me figure out each step